# How to destructure nested objects in for-loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop, ecmascript-6, destructuring

```
var users = [
   { user: "Name1",geo:{lat:'12',long:'13'} },
   { user: "Name2",geo:{lat:'12',long:'13'}, age: 2 },
   { user: "Name2",geo:{lat:'12',long:'13'} },
   { user: "Name3",geo:{lat:'12',long:'13'}, age: 4 }
 ];
```

Above is the array of objects.

Here is the `for-loop` I destructured and get user and age but I want lat and long also how will I do that ? I want it through destructuring and `for-loop` like I did with user and age

```
for (let { user, age = "DEFAULT AGE" } of users) {
  console.log(user, age);
}
```

Comment: Add `, geo: {lat, lang}` (or `long`, depending on spelling)?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You can use this:

```
for (let {user, age = "DEFAULT AGE", geo: {lat, long}} of users) {
  console.log(user, age, lat, long);
}
```

---

You have already successfully destructured `user` (simply by the property name in the object) and `age` (with a default value as well).

To use nested [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment), step by step, simply put the property name `geo` in there as well, since that’s the next property on the objects you’re iterating over that contains your needed values:

`{user, age = "DEFAULT AGE", geo}` — this would yield `{lat: "12", long: "13"}` for `geo`.

To access the nested properties directly, follow the object structure:

`{user, age = "DEFAULT AGE", geo: {}}` — this would just validate that `geo` is indeed an object.

Then, list the properties you want to access in that object:

`{user, age = "DEFAULT AGE", geo: {lat, long}}` — this would yield `"12"` for `lat` and `"13"` for `long`.

You could even go a step further and *rename* those properties:

`{user, age = "DEFAULT AGE", geo: {lat: latitude, long: longitude}}` — this would yield `"12"` for `latitude` and `"13"` for `longitude`.

---

These are the basic cases for destructuring objects:

- `name` means “just assign the entire value to `name`”.
- `{}` means “check that the value to be destructured is an object or can be converted into one, i.e. is neither `null` nor `undefined`; create no variables”.
- `{ prop }` means “get the value of `prop` as the variable `prop`”.
- `{ prop: rename }` means “follow the `prop` property and get its value as the variable `rename`”<sup>1</sup>.
- `{ prop = value }` means “get the value of `prop` as the variable `prop`, but assign `value` if `prop` yields `undefined`”<sup>2</sup>.

For the “rename” case, the rules apply recursively: `rename` is like `name`, so it can be replaced by `{}`, or `{ anotherProp }`, or `{ anotherProp: anotherRename }`, or `{ anotherProp = anotherDefault }`, etc.

Other properties on the same object level may be added via commas, like `{propA, propB}`.

For arrays, similar cases exist: `[]` would validate that the value to be destructured is an *iterable* object; `[a, b]` has the same meaning as `{0: a, 1: b}`; etc.

---

1: Note that in the case of `{ prop: something }` no variable `prop` is created.

2: “yields `undefined`” means that `obj.prop` would be equal to `undefined` which means either that the property exists and has the literal value `undefined` or that the property doesn’t exist.

Answer (score 1):

If you're just trying to find a given user and return the geo for it, this will do:

`users.find( u => u.user === 'Name1' ).geo;`

Keep in mind, you would want to do some checks aginst your 'find result' before trying to use it. For example:

```
const user = users.find( u => u.user === 'Name1' );

if (user && user.hasOwnProperty('geo')) {
    console.log(user.geo);
}
```