# How to destructure nested variable from the array

Tags: javascript, destructuring

my obj looks like that:

```
blogPost: {
  questions: 
    [
      {
        id: 234
      }
    ]
}
```

I would like to destructure `id`, but this doesn’t seem correct.

```
const {questions[0]: {id}} = blogPost
```

Comment: See [How to destructure nested objects in for-loop](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50918381/4642212).

Answer (score 3):

Use [array destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Array_destructuring) as well to make it work:

```js
{questions:[{id}]}=blogPost
```

Alternatively, you can use object destructuring on arrays as well (arrays are objects), but that is less semantical:

```js
{questions:{'0':{id}}}=blogPost
```

That accesses the property in a different way: array destructuring calls `Symbol.iterator` method to iterate over the array, while object destructuring does a `[[Get]]` operation on the specified keys only.

Comment: interesting! I didn't know it was possible to destructure a nested object. With the above operation you also declared a variable named "questions", or just the "id" one?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
const { questions } = blogPost;
const { id } = questions[0];
```