# Deeply nested Arrays and objects

Tags: javascript

I am trying to destructure an object. There is an array of objects I would like to pull into the assignment. Do I have to do a reduce on the array?

I tried to destructure the object but it only shows the first object in the Shoes Array.

```
const currentInventory = [
  {
    name: 'Brunello Cucinelli',
    shoes: [
      {name: 'tasselled black low-top lace-up', price: 1000},
      {name: 'tasselled green low-top lace-up', price: 1100},
      {name: 'plain beige suede moccasin', price: 950},
      {name: 'plain olive suede moccasin', price: 1050}
    ]
  },
  {
    name: 'Gucci',
    shoes: [
      {name: 'red leather laced sneakers', price: 800},
      {name: 'black leather laced sneakers', price: 900}
    ]
  }
];

for(var{name:designerName, shoes:[{name:shoeName,price}]} of currentInventory){
    console.log (designerName, shoeName, price)
}
```

[image]

Comment: This question might already have an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50918251/how-to-destructure-nested-objects-in-for-loop#50918381

Comment: "Do I have to do a reduce on the array?" one possibility. Destructuring is not meant for variable size structures, and logically, i don't see how you would imagine this to give you more than the first element of `shoes`.

Comment: @Brian that actually answered my question; however, it wasn't relevant to the code I had already had before it. But thank you anyway for your assistance.

Comment: @ASDFGerte I want to have efficient code. I am new to coding however, endless If else loops make reading and understanding code hard. I appreciate you input, and I will apply it for the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do another loop for `shoes` array:

```js
for (var { name: designerName, shoes } of currentInventory) {
  for (var { name: shoeName, price } of shoes) {
    console.log(designerName, shoeName, price)
  }
}
```

Comment: I so though I tried that but I guess I didn't You're a life saver.

Comment: I just tried it and it almost got me the answer I needed.